# where to use this code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005, aspnetdb

where to use this code :

```
EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = N'myASPNetDB', 
   @filename1 = N'c:\mypathdata\myaspnet.mdf', 
   @filename2 = N'c:\mypathlogs\myaspnet_log.ldf'
```

Comment: Other question, where do you have this sql from and do you know what it's doing? Have a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You would run that within SQL Server Management Studio.